# How to replace files in a folder by webpack's config in JHipster?

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

I want to replace files in a folder by webpack's config in JHipster. For example, dev-config replaces files in "`webapp/app/home`" folder with "`environments/dev/home`".

I know *`@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser`* in pure Angular can replace files in configurations, but it is not used in JHipster and does not seem to be able to replace files in a folder.

Comment: Isn't it what JHipster already does using copy-webpack-plugin in `webpack/webpack.common.js` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added a parameter for only a angular's component html as your suggestion, but it seemed it was not compiled. Does copy-webpack-plugin copy files before compile?

Comment: Yes probably, I don't know if it can be changed see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/issues/195.

Comment: Rather than using webpack to do it, have you considered doing it before calling webpack in package.json in "webpack:dev" and "webpack:prod"? Although, if you must do it in webpack, you could define a constant and test it inside your component or template, this is a common practice and JHipster already does it using webpack.DefinePlugin.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help, but I cannot understand your suggestions.

Finally, I have decided getting the all files under a folder and set to hostReplacementPaths in AngularCompilerPlugin.

I wrote as below.

tenant-util.js

```
const TENANT_ARG_KEY = '--tenant=';

module.exports = {
    getTenant
};

/**
 * webpack arg example： --tenant=company1
 * @param {string[]} argv process.argv
 */
function getTenant(argv /* : string[] */) /* : string */ {
    if (!Array.isArray(argv)) {
        return '';
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < argv.length; ++i) {
        if (!argv[i].startsWith(TENANT_ARG_KEY)) {
            continue;
        }
        return argv[i].substr(TENANT_ARG_KEY.length);
    }

    return '';
}
```

webpack.common.js

```
const tenantUtils = require('./tenant-utils');
const tenant = tenantUtils.getTenant(process.argv);

const hostReplacementPaths = {};
if (tenant) {
    const glob = require('glob');
    const replaceToFolder = `environments/${tenant}`;
    const filenamesInEnvironment = glob.sync(`./src/${replaceToFolder}/**/*.*`);
    if (!filenamesInEnvironment) {
        throw Error('check the tenant setting');
    }
    for (const filename of filenamesInEnvironment) {
        const originalFilename = filename.replace(replaceToFolder, 'main/webapp')
        hostReplacementPaths[originalFilename] = filename;
    }
}


...
        new AngularCompilerPlugin({
            mainPath: utils.root('src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts'),
            tsConfigPath: utils.root('tsconfig.app.json'),
            sourceMap: true,
            hostReplacementPaths: hostReplacementPaths
        }),
```